# How can I use array_merge in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

I have two arrays `$array1` and `$array2` and I want to merge them in smarty template for further processing. I dont want to do this in php as I have to use them separately too, how I can merge two arrays in smarty tpl?

Comment: Dependend on your security configuration and smarty version, you can simple do `{assign 'array_merged' $array1|array_merge:$array2}`.

Comment: Thanks @sofl this is what I was looking for, Can you post it as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dependent on your security configuration and smarty version, you can simple do

```
{assign 'array_merged' $array1|array_merge:$array2}
```

For more informations about the correct security setting, look at this http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.tpl#advanced.features.security

> $php_functions is an array of PHP functions that are considered trusted and can be used from within template. To disable access to all PHP functions set $php_functions = null. An empty array ( $php_functions = array() ) will allow all PHP functions. The default is array('isset', 'empty', 'count', 'sizeof', 'in_array', 'is_array','time','nl2br').

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// This is effectively the same as assign()
$smarty->append('foo', 'Fred');
// After this line, foo will now be seen as an array in the template
$smarty->append('foo', 'Albert');

$array = array(1 => 'one', 2 => 'two');
$smarty->append('X', $array);
$array2 = array(3 => 'three', 4 => 'four');
// The following line will add a second element to the X array
$smarty->append('X', $array2);

// passing an associative array    
$smarty->append(array('city' => 'Lincoln', 'state' => 'Nebraska'));
?>
```

You could create a new variable by appending both arrays to a new variable.

See documentation [here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.append.tpl).

Comment: thanks for your answer but I really want to do this in Smrty tpl file do you have any other suggestions, which can really help me with this.